# Stretch CSS nav bar across whole page

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my site https://nhallowe.w3.uvm.edu/cs008/assignment5.0/

I want the nav bar to stretch across the whole page, now it stops as it approaches the edge and is uneven. I want it to reach to both ends of the page and have the words be centered. Thank you for any help

HTML and PHP

```
<ul>
    <?php

    if ($path_parts['filename'] == "index") {
        print '<li class="activePage"><a id = "home">Home</a></li>';
    } else {
        print '<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>';
    }
    if ($path_parts['filename'] == "james") {
        print '<li class="activePage"><a id = "home">Social Media</a></li>';
    } else {
        print '<li><a href="data.php">Social Media</a></li>';
    }
    if ($path_parts['filename'] == "woods") {
        print '<li class="activePage"><a id = "home">Videos</a></li>';
    } else {
        print '<li><a href="woods.php">Videos</a></li>';
    }
    if ($path_parts['filename'] == "gretzky") {
        print '<li class="activePage"><a id = "home">Coaching</a></li>';
    } else {
        print '<li><a href="gretzky.php">Coaching</a></li>';
    }
    if ($path_parts['filename'] == "gretzky") {
        print '<li class="activePage"><a id = "home">About Me</a></li>';
    } else {
        print '<li><a href="gretzky.php">About Me</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
    ul { 
        list-style-type: none;
}
ul li { 
    float: left;
}
ul li a { 
        font-family: 'Corben', Georgia, Times, serif;
    background: #000000; 
    color: white; 
    display: block; 
    padding: 30px 70px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}

#home { 
        font-family: 'Corben', Georgia, Times, serif;
    background: #192faa; 
    color: white; 
    display: block; 
    padding: 30px 70px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}

ul li a:hover { 
    background: #192faa; 
}
```

Comment: @user3808597 see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AwWUA/9/) demo and you might get your answer

Comment: try `ul { 
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and you wont have to give `li width` manually

```
ul {
display: table;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
display: table-cell;
//remove float property
}
```

Comment: how would i center the words though

Comment: @user3808597 add `text-align: center;` in your `a` anchor css of list

Answer (score 0):

First, in `CSS` set the width of `ul` to `ul {width:100%}`.

Then, because there are 5 `<li>` elements, set each one to `il {width:20%;}`
Make sure to remove any other height/width `CSS` regarding to each `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul { 
    display: table;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul > li { 
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```